# Trying to select only the smallest value in a loop of tk.Entry methods for the same textvariable

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Not sure if theres a way to make individual textvariables for each tk.Entry method in the loop

```py
fastestlap = 1000000000000
lapsno = lapsvar.get()

for i in range(1, (lapsno+1)):
    laptimevar(i) = tk.IntVar()

    self.asktime = tk.Label(self.main, text=f"what was your time for lap {i}")
    self.entertime = tk.Entry(self.main, textvariable= laptimevar(i))

    if laptimevar(i) < fastestlap:
        fastestlap = laptimevar(i)

    self.asktime.pack()
    self.entertime.pack()
```

it doesn't like the use of the (i) in the `laptimevar(i) = tk.IntVar()`

Am new to this and not sure how else I woud do this, please help!

Comment: Have you tried just deleting it, if *it* doesn't like it. Why bother them ?

Comment: What is `laptimevar`? Is it a `list`? If it is, indexing a list utilizes `[]` not `()`. Also, welcome to stackoverflow. Please checkout [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It's unclear. Do you want to enumerate values of ```Entry``` widgets? Then, why not store that ```tk.IntVar()``` instances into a list? You should learn how to use the list first.